# how to group products on shopping cart page according to category in opencart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

We want to fetch data in cart page according to category to apply discount on total amount according to no. of products of same category.

In model file

```
public function getCategory($data)
{   
    $sql = "SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "Product_to_category where product_id='".$data."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach($query as $key=>$value)
    {       
        //print_r($key); echo "=>"; print_r($value);
        foreach($value as $k=>$v)
        {   
            //echo $k."=>".$v;
            return $k."=".$v;
        }   
    }       
}
```

In controller file /catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

```
$r[]=$this->model_discount_cdiscount->getCategory($product['product_id']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
////////////// Grouping Same category products into one array //////////////

$category_id = $this->model_discount_cdiscount->getcategory($product['product_id']);

$array_key = $category_id[0]['category_id']; 

if (array_key_exists($array_key, $this->data['discount']))
{

    $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['total'] = $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['total']+(preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","",$total));
    $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['quantity'] = $this->data['discount'][$array_key]['quantity']+$product['quantity'];
}
else
{
    $this->data['discount'][$array_key] = array(
            'category_name' => $category_id[0]['name'],
            'category_id' => $array_key,
            'total' => (preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","",$total)),
            'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
            'length' => $product['length']
        );
}
```

-

Answer (score 1):

Your model function is wrong.

First of all, `$this->db->query($sql)` returns an object with properties `row`, `rows` and `num_rows`. Therefore Your first `foreach` loop is wrong.

Second, if You select category ids from `product_to_ctegory` for one concrete product, You always have to expect array of category ids, therefore You'd have to stick with `$query->rows` property. And the second `foreach` loop has completely no sense to me...

So this should be Your method:

```
public function getCategories($product_id) {   
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = " . (int)$product_id);
    $categories = array();
    foreach($query->rows as $row) {
        $categories[] = $row['category_id'];
    }
    echo "Product ({$product_id}) is linked to categories with IDs: " . implode(', ', $categories);
}
```

Notice also the SQL query variable typecasting - to avoid SQL injection...

Though I am not sure what do You want to achieve by loading all the categories for a product, I believe I got You on the right way. Anyway, it may be more usable for You if You only select the main (1<sup>st</sup> level) categories (with `parent_id === 0`), so the query might look like:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT c.category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category ptc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category c ON c.category_id = ptc.category_id WHERE ptc.product_id = " . (int)$product_id . " AND c.parent_id = 0");
```

This, of course, requires that all the products are properly linked (nested) to the categories - from the top to the bottom levels (I have seen many live systems, where proucts were linked only to the bottom level categories...).

Comment: @shadyyx-- Actually in cart page in opencart I want to show product in category wise for eg.:-If we add product A, B and C which belong two Categories X And Y . 

IF added product A which belongs to category X and Y . How we find that particular add product belongs to which category.

Actually we tried to applied discount categorywise on added product in cart page .How we do this?

Please give me suggestions to solve this.

Comment: And this, my friend, is a real magic :-) No easy solution. My opinion would be to create a new table for this *categorywise* discounts and to set only one category for each product from which the discount would be calculated. This would mean a new table, few modifications in product administration and changes in the cart to be able to apply the discounts... Could be pretty tricky and I wish You good luck!